# How do I sync tests in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have **CommentsList** component which displays a list with all the comments. Each comment has a 'Reply to' button that opens the **AddComment** component (this component allows me to add a reply to a comment). To display the AddComment component for each comment, I used an array of states.

The **AddComment** component contains a text area for the input, a cancel button and a submit button. When I click on the submit button and the reply is added successfully, the **AddComment** component closes. If the input is empty and I click on the submit button, the component doesn't close because the input can't be empty in order to be submitted successfully.
I want to test this functionality so that I can verify if the **AddComment** component disappears after I post a reply.

The problem is that in tests my **AddComment** component *doesn't disappear* when I click on the submit button. What I noticed is that the comment is added succesfully, but the state of the **AddComment** component for the comment isn't changed. When I click on submit button the input is submitted, but the function that changes the state is never called. I think the problem might be the fact that the actions don't synchronize.

I tried to use await act to render **CommentsList** component to make sure that the test run closer to how React works in the browser, but my **AddComment** component still doesn't disappear.

Here's my CommentsList component

```
function CommentsList(props) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [hasReplyCommentBox, setHasReplyCommentBox] = useState([]);

  function toggleHasReplyComment(commentIndex) {
    var auxState = { ...hasReplyCommentBox };
    auxState[commentIndex] = auxState[commentIndex] ? 0 : 1;
    setHasReplyCommentBox(auxState);
  }

  function replyToCommentButton(commentIndex) {
    return [
      <span
        id={"replyButton-" + commentIndex}
        onClick={() => toggleHasReplyComment(commentIndex)}>
        {t('Reply to')}
      </span>
    ];
  }

  function commentReplyBox(commentIndex, parentCommentId) {
    return hasReplyCommentBox[commentIndex]
      ?
      <AddComment
        id={props.codeId}
        parentCommentId={parentCommentId}
        commentIndex={commentIndex}
        toggleHasReplyComment={toggleHasReplyComment}
        updateComments={props.updateComments}
      />
      :
      null
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout>
        <List
          itemLayout="horizontal"
          dataSource={props.comments}
          renderItem={(comment, commentIndex) => (
            <List.Item>
              <CommentCard
                userId={comment.user_id}
                datePosted={comment.date_posted}
                body={comment.body}
                actions={replyToCommentButton(commentIndex)}
                children={commentReplyBox(commentIndex, comment.id)}
              />
            </List.Item>
          )}
        />
        <AddComment
          id={props.codeId}
          updateComments={props.updateComments}
        />
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Here's my AddComment component

```
function AddComment(props) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { TextArea } = Input;
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [comment, setComment] = useState();
  const [onCommentAddSuccess, setOnCommentAddSuccess] = useState(0);

  const buttonStyle = {
    float: 'right'
  };

  function onCommentChange(newComment) {
    setComment(newComment.target.value);
  }

  function updateOnCommentAddSuccess(onCommentAddSuccess) {
    setOnCommentAddSuccess(onCommentAddSuccess + 1);
  }

  function resetCommentInput() {
    setComment('');
  }

  function onFormReset() {
    form.resetFields();
  }

  function toggleHasReplyCommentOnPost(parentCommentId, commentIndex) {
    if (parentCommentId !== undefined) {
      console.log('comentariu adaugat cu succes');
      props.toggleHasReplyComment(commentIndex);
    }
  }

  function submitComment() {
    let request = {
      body: comment,
      code_id: props.id,
      parent_comment_id: props.parentCommentId
    };
    fetch('/api/comment/add',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
      }
    ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success === 1) {
        updateOnCommentAddSuccess(onCommentAddSuccess);
        props.updateComments(onCommentAddSuccess);
        resetCommentInput();
        toggleHasReplyCommentOnPost(props.parentCommentId, props.commentIndex);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Form form={form} name="comment" className="comment-form"
        onFinish={submitComment}>
        <Form.Item name="body" label={t('Comment')}>
          <TextArea placeholder={t('Leave a comment')}
            onChange={onCommentChange}
            id={"parent-comment-" + props.parentCommentId} />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item style={buttonStyle}>
          <Space>
            {props.parentCommentId
              ?
              <Button id={"cancelAddReplyComment-" + props.parentCommentId}
                  type="secondary" className = "comment-form-button"
                  onClick={
                    () => props.toggleHasReplyComment(props.commentIndex)
                  }>
                  {t('Cancel')}
              </Button>
              :
              null
            }
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit"
              className = "comment-form-button"
              id={"post-comment-button-" + props.parentCommentId}
              onClick={onFormReset}>
              {t('Post')}
            </Button>
          </Space>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

And here's how my test looks like

```
test ('Toggle displaying add reply to comments', async () => {
  const comments = [
    {
      id: 'ID-1',
      user_id: 'USER-ID-1',
      date_posted: '2020-01-01 01:00:00',
      body: 'First comment'
    }
  ];

  await act(async () => {
    Promise.resolve(render(
      <CommentsList comments={comments} />, container
    ));
  });

  // Open AddComment component
  const replyButton = container.querySelector("#replyButton-0");
  await fireEvent.click(replyButton);
  
  // Insert input in the text area
  const userInput = container.querySelector("#parent-comment-ID-1");
  await userEvent.type((userInput), 'reply');
  
  // Submit the input
  const postButton = container.querySelector("#post-comment-button-ID-1");
  await fireEvent.click(postButton);
  
  // Check if the AddComment component is closed
  expect(container.querySelector("#cancelAddReplyComment-ID-1")).toBeFalsy();
});
```